# How to rename all the images in a directory with name coming from an excel cell values?

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a folder with images that are currently named with some random image numbers. I want to rename all the images in the directory with a specific column of an excel sheet which I put on a data frame.

Note: The random number of images is the last part of the excel value. For example, if an image name in the folder is 'img1097' then in the excel sheet I can find the image in the column as 'First_Second_img1097'. So in the folder, I have images with names like 'img1098', 'img1099' etc, and in the data frame, I have values like as follows:

```
#my_dataframe

**Column**

First_Second_img1097

Table_Chairs_img1098

Cat_Image_img1099
```

I have been trying to implement different options with no luck. Here is my code:

```
    import os,re
    path = r'myfolder\user\allimages\Main\target'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for index, file in enumerate(files):
        tempname = file.split('.')[0] #no extentions
        for i in tempname :
             for picture_name in my_dataframe['Column']:
                     if temp_file_name == picture_name:
                          os.rename(os.path.join(path, file),                             
                          os.path.join(path,str(index) + '.jpg'))
```

I'm expecting an answer where I will be able to rename all the matching images with the cell values of the dataframe's "column" column. so 'img1097' should be renamed with 'First_Second_img1097'. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: your `picture_name` here is `First_Second_img1097`. So you need to do `short_picture_name = picture_name.split('_')[-1]`. Now you compare your `temp_file_name == short_picture_name `

Comment: I don't want to do this as I want the entire value of the 'column's cell value. so 'img1097' should be renamed with 'First_Second_img1097'. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Also, my picture name is 'img1097'.

Comment: Answer updated with everything working!! Please upvote and accept the answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
import ntpath
import os,re

path = r'myfolder\user\allimages\Main\target'
pathlist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        pathlist.append(os.path.join(root, name))

for new_path in pathlist:
    file_name = ntpath.basename(new_path)
    tempname = file_name.split('.')[0] 
    for index, row in df["Columns"].iteritems(): 
        new_row = row.split('_')[-1] ## Gives img1097
        new_tempname = tempname.replace(" ", "") ## makes img 1097 to img1097
        if new_row == new_tempname: ## Now the matching will work
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join(path, str(row)+'.jpg'))
```

Comment: I'm getting this below error:

[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'myfolder\user\allimages\Main\target\\170752.jpg\\' -> 'myfolder\user\allimages\Main\target\\170752.jpg\\Table_Chairs_img1098_170752.jpg'

Comment: so `path` variable will contain the path where your images are stored. so if you are getting this error, that means your files are not at that location, give the right location

Comment: I have the images in the same folder only, and also the row is returning all the renamed file name, not understanding the issue here.

Comment: So everything right now what i have posted is correct. It is just that you are not able to figure out how to rename those files? Correct?

Answer (score 1):

To rename all image files in your directory, you can try the following python program. Just run the python script and the files will be automatically renamed corresponding to excel cell values:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os
import glob

# Your directory
mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\','/') + '/'

# Get data of cells from excel
df=pd.read_excel(r''+ mydir +'test.xlsx')
for i in range(len(df['Name'])):
    print( df['Name'][i])
number_of_cell=len(df['Name'])

# Get the list of specified files in a directory
filelist=os.listdir(mydir)
for file in filelist[:]: # filelist[:] makes a copy of filelist.
    if not(file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg')):
        filelist.remove(file)
print (filelist)
number_of_files=len(filelist)

# Rename all files in directory with a value of cell in excel
for i in range(number_of_files):
    os.rename(mydir+ filelist[i], mydir+ df['Name'][i] + '.' + os.path.splitext(filelist[i])[1][1:])

print ('Success')
```

This is the excel file:
[image: excel file]

The file name of all images before and after:
[image: files before it were named]

[image: files after being renamed]

==== EDITED ====

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os
import glob

# Your directory
mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\','/') + '/'

# Get data of cells from excel
df=pd.read_excel(r''+ mydir +'Book1.xlsx')
for i in range(len(df['New_Image_Name'])):
    print( df['New_Image_Name'][i])
number_of_cell=len(df['New_Image_Name'])

# Get the list of specified files in a directory
filelist=os.listdir(mydir)
for file in filelist[:]: # filelist[:] makes a copy of filelist.
    if not(file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg')):
        filelist.remove(file)
print (filelist)
number_of_files=len(filelist)

# Rename all files in directory with a value of cell in excel
# Files will be ranamed with cell value if the digits of last name of file is matched with the last digits in excel cell
for i in range(number_of_files):
    for n in range(number_of_cell):
        if ((((df['New_Image_Name'][n].split('_'))[len((df['New_Image_Name'][n].split('_')))-1]).split('.'))[0] == (((filelist[i].split('_'))[len((filelist[i].split('_')))-1]).split('.'))[0]):
            os.rename(mydir+ filelist[i], mydir+ df['New_Image_Name'][n] + '.' + os.path.splitext(filelist[i])[1][1:])
            break

print ('Success')
```

The file name of all images before and after:

files before it were named
[image]

The file after being renamed
[image]
Hope this can help you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But there's a problem with your code. You didn't account for the fact that we need to match that we need to compare the '1097' for the image with the image name. For example 'img1097' should be renamed only with a cell value that contains 'First_Second_img1097'. So 1097 should be the matching key here which is not here, I readjusted but now it is not working. So for your code, it is just renaming all the images with the cell values of the excel. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: oh i see, i will update this to match with your purpose, wait for a while.

Comment: what is this '-4' doing in  if (df['Name'][n][len(df['Name'][n])-4:]? I'm sorry I didn't get it here. I can't hardcode it like this as the name not necessarily will be in 4 letters.

Comment: '-4' means to get the last 4 digits of number of filename or cell value. Example :
image file with the name is 'file1234.png', with '-4' we can get only the 4 digits of unique number, so the result is '1234'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193513/discussion-between-user11409134-and-mf-al-fafa).